# How to wrap a <myClass*, myClass*> C++ dictionary using SWIG for Python and .NET

Tags: .net, c++, python, dictionary, swig

I'm wrapping C++ code into Python and .NET code by using SWIG 2.0.0.

I'm able to wrap a (myClass*, std::string) by introducing the following sentence in the "interface.i" file:

```
%template(Dictionary_myClass_String) std::map<myClass*, std::string>;
```

But I'm getting several errors if i try this:

```
%template(Dictionary_myClass_myClass) std::map<myClass*, myClass*>;
```

Question:
Is this wrapping type possible?

Thanks!
Javier

Comment: Can you post the errors please? Are they SWIG errors, or compile errors, or something else?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your help. Sure, the errors are: error C2084: function 'PyObject *std_map_Sl_myClass_Sm__Sc_myClass_Sm__Sg__items(std::map<_Kty,_Ty> *)' already has a body

Comment: error C2084: function 'swig::SwigPyIterator *std_map_Sl_myClass_Sm__Sc_myClass_Sm__Sg__iterator(std::map<_Kty,_Ty> *,PyObject **)' already has a body